# Why hot air cools off when it rises and expands?

Tags: atmospheric-science, gas

I know that when air is heated it will have a high temperature that leads to high kinetic energy of particles,high pressure, low density. But, why when hot air rises and expand they get cold ?

Please answer in long sentence.

Comment: The hot rises because it has lower density than cold one. As it rises it does work and loses energy, hence it is getting colder. This is called adiabatic expansion.